# GWT: Is it ok to call ensureInjected() in onModuleLoad?

Tags: gwt, gwt2

In [this documentation page](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CssResource) it is adviced to use `ensureInjected()` per view/widgets:

> The recommended pattern is to call ensureInjected() in the static
>   initializer of your various widget types

But my use case is one shared .css file (and its corresponding `CSSResource`) among all views in application. Do I really have to call `ensureInjected()` for this `CSSResource` in all my views?

An alternative seems to be calling this method just in `onModuleLoad()` and than access the CSS resource from singleton. Is it legitimate approach? Does it it have any drawbacks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What matters is that `ensureInjected()` is called at least once before you display anything referencing the `CssResource`, otherwise the stylesheet won't be present, and there would be no style to apply matching the class names.

So yes, it's OK to call `ensureInjected()` only once in`onModuleLoad`.

And you don't have to use a singleton, all instances of a given `ClientBundle` will share the same resource instances (they'll be generated as singletons).